Error when trying to install spatstat.core
I have R 4.3.3 and I am trying to use phenoptr via RStudio to merge/ consolidate/ analyze qptiff files. When I try to install phenoptr, it says that I don't have spatstat.core. When I try to download spatstat.core, it says the package is not available for this version of R. Both errors pasted below.
devtools::install_github("akoyabio/phenoptr")
Downloading GitHub repo akoyabio/phenoptr@HEAD
Skipping 1 packages not available: spatstat.core
── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\krcon\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUvqT8r\remotes847c67818ab\akoyabio-phenoptr-7d5dcea/DESCRIPTION' (658ms)
─  preparing 'phenoptr': (1.8s)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (360ms)
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building 'phenoptr_0.3.2.tar.gz'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/krcon/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependency 'spatstat.core' is not available for package 'phenoptr'

removing 'C:/Users/krcon/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/phenoptr'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
installation of package ‘C:/Users/krcon/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUvqT8r/file847c26d57dbb/phenoptr_0.3.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status


install.packages("spatstat.core")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/krcon/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘spatstat.core’ is not available for this version of R

I tried to download spatstat.core from the zip file found on the website:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/index.html
However, I cannot figure out next steps to download spatstat

spatstat.core no longer exists. It has been replaced by two packages, spatstat.explore and spatstat.model. This happened 4 years ago. See the GitHub repository
It appears that the package you want to install, phenoptr, has not been updated to use the current spatstat family. In particular it should depend on spatstat.explore and spatstat.model instead of spatstat.core.
I suggest you contact the maintainer of phenoptr asking them to update their package.
